# Piezo contact mic into iMac - avoid signal spikes

Tags: audio, microphone, computers, piezoelectricity, hacking

I've wired an external piezo as contact mic to the TRRS 3.5 jack of an iMac and it is working fine - BUT the signal will just randomly stop after hitting the contact mic several times too hard, so I suspect the iMac kills the connection after it gets too high voltage spikes from the mic...?

How can I avoid/dampen these signal spikes?

This is the way it's wired (needs to have that 10k in parallel for the mac to recognise it as a mic and the 33ohms are there to fake the speakers on L/R channels)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I just found a solution - it's rather hacky I guess, but it suits my needs. Using two LEDs as a limiter to avoid voltage spikes. I took the idea from here: http://www.zachpoff.com/diy-resources/simple-contact-mike

Answer (score -1):

[Here is an interesting article](http://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2012/apr/protecting-inputs-in-digital-electronics) on protecting digital inputs using resistors, zener diodes and capacitors.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.  Your link deals with protecting digital inputs, while this question deals with preventing an audio input from changing modes.