# Piezo contact mic into MacBook air

Tags: audio, microphone, piezoelectricity

I'm wiring an external piezo as contact mic to the TRRS 3.5 jack of a MacBook Air.
I'm following the instructions on this post:
[Piezo contact mic into iMac - avoid signal spikes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/183148/piezo-contact-mic-into-imac-avoid-signal-spikes/183163#183163?newreg=fa2f678ec77946c990c411eab3a53d94)

However, the answer to this question is not clear, and the provided link in the answer to this question is now dead.

Where in the circuit should I add the two LEDs to prevent signal spikes?
[image: Piezo circuit diagram]

I am new to wiring microphones, so please let me know if I am omitting any information that you need to answer this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two LED's should be connected in anti-parallell like this, in order to limit the voltage from the piezo.
[image: Schematic with LED's added]

By the way, you can often open dead links with [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20160807170838/https://www.zachpoff.com/diy-resources/simple-contact-mike).

Comment: Thanks for the information, this is really helpful!